# C++ map values not changing on run time, what am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, debugging, dictionary

I have a map in a global class for my game called realMap. It is used to store variables in the map that all objects in the game can access as long as realMap is in scope. Basically like `global.` in Gamemaker. So everything in the map is stored on run time.

This is the map initializing code
`std::map<const char*, Real> realMap;`
(`Real` is in another file declared to `double`.)

In my player object, when it starts, the player does
`globalObject.realMap["playerDead"] = false;`

So I check and it's equal to 0.

But then when the player dies, it's supposed to set the map key to `true`, but it doesn't. I did a displayed message to check it's value and it's still 0.
Here is the code:

```
ObjGlobal->realMap["playerDead"] = true;
Real tempVal = ObjGlobal->realMap.at("playerDead");
agk::Message(agk::Str(int(tempVal)));
```

So as I stated, agk::Message displays 0.

What am I doing wrong? I'm still new to maps and kinda new to C++ in general so sorry if it's a stupid mistake.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you using `Real` (`double....`) to store a boolean???!?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using a pointer to a string literal as the key to the map, but you have two different `"playerDead"` strings in your code. Unless your linker is optimising the two strings into the same pointer (an optimisation many linkers do - but do not have to) then the keys will actually end up being different.

If you change your map definition to `std::map<std::string, Real>` it should work as expected, as the key will actually be based on the content of the string rather than its address in memory.

Comment: Thanks so much! I never thought about that.